# How to show status bar initially hidden from plist iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, hide, statusbar, info.plist

i want to hide the status bar when i launch my app to view launch image that was covered by status bar. so in plist i added

```
Status bar is initially hidden YES
```

and status bar is covered. 
My problem is that status bar is covered always in my app, i want to hide status bar only for launch image, what can i do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SOLVED

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:NO];
```

using this at launch of app :)

Answer (score 13):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

Comment: This signature of setStatusBarHidden has been deprecated since iOS 3.2. See below for the proper signature.

Answer (score 6):

you can do this by adding property, "Status bar Initially Hidden" to plist as shown below : - [image]

Answer (score 3):

OR

you can also set the (Status bar Initially Hidden)Property to "NO" in Info.plist file in your Application.

Just uncheck this property.

Answer (score 3):

Neither Niko's nor JackTurky's solutions are correct. Niko's:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

...works but is deprecated. Correct in iOS 3.2 and later is:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```