# How can I keep the status bar always the same orientation as the root view

Tags: objective-c, ios, orientation

I get the current device orientation by :

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation
```

When my app starts, some initial work will be done and this cause my root view can not be rotated for a short time. However during that period the state bar is able to be rotated. So, the orientation I get is not the orientation of my root view if the root view and the state bar is not at the same orientation. How can I make sure that both is always at the same orientation?

Answer (score 0):

You can launch the app with the status bar hidden while you do your work under a splash screen, then show the status bar when you are ready to from the view controller.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531989/how-to-show-status-bar-initially-hidden-from-plist-iphone) for some code.